# Write to HDFS running in Docker from another Docker container running Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, docker, hdfs

I have a docker image for spark + jupyter (https://github.com/zipfian/spark-install)

I have another docker image for hadoop. (https://github.com/kiwenlau/hadoop-cluster-docker)

I am running 2 containers from the above 2 images in Ubuntu.
For the first container: 
  I am able to successfully launch jupyter and run python code:

```
   import pyspark
   sc = pyspark.sparkcontext('local[*]')
   rdd = sc.parallelize(range(1000))
   rdd.takeSample(False,5)
```

For the second container:

In the host Ubuntu OS, I am able to successfully go to the

- web browser localhost:8088 : And browse the Hadoop all applications
- localhost:50070: and browse the HDFS file system.

[image]

Now I want to write to the HDFS file system (running in the 2nd container) from jupyter (running in the first container).

So I add the additional line

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:///user/root/input/test")
```

I get the error:

***HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///user/root/input/test***

Am I giving the hdfs path incorrectly ?

My understanding is that, I should be able to talk to a docker container running hdfs from another container running spark. Am I missing anything ?

Thanks for your time.

I haven't tried docker compose yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URI `hdfs:///user/root/input/test` is missing an authority (hostname) section and port. To write to hdfs in another container you would need to fully specify the URI and make sure the two containers were on the same network and that the HDFS container has the ports for the namenode and data node exposed.

For example, you might have set the host name for the HDFS container to be `hdfs.container`. Then you can write to that HDFS instance using the URI `hdfs://hdfs.container:8020/user/root/input/test` (assuming the Namenode is running on 8020). Of course you will also need to make sure that the path you're seeking to write has the correct permissions as well.

So to do what you want:

- Make sure your HDFS container has the namenode and datanode ports exposed. You can do this using an `EXPOSE` directive in the dockerfile (the container you linked does not have these) or using the `--expose` argument when invoking `docker run`. The default ports are 8020 and 50010 (for NN and DN respectively).
- Start the containers on the same network. If you just do `docker run` with no `--network` they will start on the default network and you'll be fine. Start the HDFS container with a specific name using the `--name` argument.
- Now modify your URI to include the proper authority (this will be the value of the docker `--name` argument you passed) and port as described above and it should work

Comment: Thank you very much Ed. I ran the two containers in the same network (user defined). Then I was able to read the hdfs file system, using hdfs:///hadoop-master:9000/user/root/input/test. (hadoop-master is the name of the container and hdfs port in the docker img was 9000 instead of 8020).

Comment: I am however struck on two other things: 1) Am not able to write to the HDFS directory from the other container  2)Not sure which directory in the hadoop container I should volume mount when starting the container so that I can persist the changes to the host

Comment: for 1) do you have an error to post for the hdfs write issue? 2) the default directory for storage is in /var/lib/... (its probably the only thing in there in the container) if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks again Ed. 1) got resolved.. was a permission issue inside the container. 2) what I am confused is: Inside the hdfs container, if I create a hdfs directory or file using the command hadoop fs touch, mkdir etc. where does the actual data gets saved ? that's the path I would want to mount to in the host ubuntu machine.. isn't my understanding correct ?

Comment: HDFS has a configuration for a path in which to save data (several in fact). The ones most likely of interest to you are dfs.datanode.data.dir and dfs.namenode.name.dir. You would want to mount these from Ubuntu to preserve data across sessions. You can find the default values for these paths here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml